# Best plugin/homegrown approach to Wordpress relevancy search?

Tags: wordpress, search

What us the best approach to work around Wordpress' default chronological behavior? What is the best plugin or method to fine tune my search results? I have found 3 candidates:

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/
http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/search-unleashed
```

Google custom search engine

Background:
I'm building a search/browse interface where users can find activities. i am writing activities as posts, then applying metadata to each post to maximize findability across a number of dimensions. i want to display results by relevancy, not chronology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

relevanssi has worked pretty well for me, I believe there is also a 'pro' version that adds more features.